# how to animate check box to the middle while scaling without pushing other checkboxes using CSS only

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Checkbox</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 20px auto;
      width: 658px;
      height: 675px;
      background-color: #5D4C46;
      padding: 2.5px;
      position: relative;
      border-radius: 8px;
    }
    div {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    input[type=checkbox] {
      display: none;
    }
    input[type=checkbox] + label {
      background: #999;
      height: 150px;
      width: 200px;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0 0 0 0px;
      transition-property: all;
      transition-duration: 2s;
    }
    input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
      background: #0080FF;
      height: 225px;
      width: 300px;
      animation: rotations 2s 2s;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    }
    @keyframes rotations {
      0% {
        transform: rotateZ(0deg)
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotateZ(360deg)
      }
    }
    img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
</body>
<div>
  <input type='checkbox' name='001' value='valuable' id="001" />
  <label for="001"></label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type='checkbox' name='002' value='valuable' id="002" />
  <label for="002"></label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type='checkbox' name='003' value='valuable' id="003" />
  <label for="003"></label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type='checkbox' name='004' value='valuable' id="004" />
  <label for="004"></label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type='checkbox' name='005' value='valuable' id="005" />
  <label for="005"></label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type='checkbox' name='006' value='valuable' id="006" />
  <label for="006"></label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type='checkbox' name='007' value='valuable' id="007" />
  <label for="007"></label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type='checkbox' name='008' value='valuable' id="008" />
  <label for="008"></label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type='checkbox' name='009' value='valuable' id="009" />
  <label for="009"></label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type='checkbox' name='010' value='valuable' id="010" />
  <label for="010"></label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type='checkbox' name='011' value='valuable' id="011" />
  <label for="011"></label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type='checkbox' name='012' value='valuable' id="012" />
  <label for="012"></label>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm trying to create an image grid, and I'm stuck with 2 issues:
1- when tapping on any image scaling should not push other images
2- on click: animate the selected image to the middle of the body while scaling

thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I've got it close to what you want, but in reverse, it doesn't do it smoothly. I used scale, instead of width and height. Hope this helps.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Checkbox</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 20px auto;
      width: 658px;
      height: 675px;
      background-color: #5D4C46;
      padding: 2.5px;
      position: relative;
      border-radius: 8px;
    }
    div {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    input[type=checkbox] {
      display: none;
    }
    input[type=checkbox] + label {
      background: #999;
      height: 150px;
      width: 200px;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0 0 0 0px;
      
      transition-property: all;
      transition-duration: 2s;
    }
    input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
      background: #0080FF;
      animation: rotations 4s forwards;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    }
    @keyframes rotations {
      0% {
        transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
      }
      50% {
        transform: scale(1.5) rotate(0deg);
      }
      100% {
        transform: scale(1.5) rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
   @keyframes resize {
      0% {
        transform: scale();
      }
      100% {
        transform: scale(1);
      }
    }
    img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
</body>
<div>
  <input type='checkbox' name='001' value='valuable' id="001" />
  <label for="001"></label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type='checkbox' name='002' value='valuable' id="002" />
  <label for="002"></label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type='checkbox' name='003' value='valuable' id="003" />
  <label for="003"></label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type='checkbox' name='004' value='valuable' id="004" />
  <label for="004"></label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type='checkbox' name='005' value='valuable' id="005" />
  <label for="005"></label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type='checkbox' name='006' value='valuable' id="006" />
  <label for="006"></label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type='checkbox' name='007' value='valuable' id="007" />
  <label for="007"></label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type='checkbox' name='008' value='valuable' id="008" />
  <label for="008"></label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type='checkbox' name='009' value='valuable' id="009" />
  <label for="009"></label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type='checkbox' name='010' value='valuable' id="010" />
  <label for="010"></label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type='checkbox' name='011' value='valuable' id="011" />
  <label for="011"></label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type='checkbox' name='012' value='valuable' id="012" />
  <label for="012"></label>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```